# Set typeface to various editTexts

Tags: android, typeface

I am developing an application with a custom font, setting the typeface is working fine, but I was wondering is there a better a way to set TypeFace to all the editTexts in my activity than put in them one by one. 
This is how  I'm doing it actually:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/NeoSans.otf");
Typeface fontBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/NeoSans-Bold.otf");


    edt_txt_nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_nombres);
    edt_txt_apellido = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_apellidos);
    edt_txt_usuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_usuario);
    edt_txt_contrasena = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contrasena);
    edt_txt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
    edt_txt_telefono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_telefono);
    edt_txt_fecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_fec_nac);

    registrar.setTypeface(fontBold);
    txt_nombre.setTypeface(font);
    txt_apellido.setTypeface(font);     
    txt_telefono.setTypeface(font);
    txt_fecha.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_nombre.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_apellido.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_usuario.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_contrasena.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_email.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_telefono.setTypeface(font);
    edt_txt_fecha.setTypeface(font);
```

Is it a better (shorter) way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `EditText` and set the typeface in the constructor:

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    // replace '...' with proper arguments
    public MyEditText(...) {
        super(...)
        // fetch your font
        this.setTypeface(myFont);
    }
}
```

Don't forget the `EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` and `EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style)` constructors in your subclass or your layout will fail to inflate.

Then in your `layout.xml`, refer to your new `MyEditText` subclass instead:

```
<com.myapp.MyEditText
    ... />
```

Comment: I was trying, your update totally saves me, thanks you!! Works fine

Comment: actually, didn't at first, I was trying with only one constructor and it doesn't crash, but the fonttype wasn't set so I override the 3 constructors to make sure and also didn't have the time to test 1 by 1 wich one was the one the app's using.